# Can't access js file in Amazon S3

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-debug-toolbar

I have a website running on Django. Trying to measure its performance with Django-Debug-Toolbar. I have installed it properly, run collectstatic and the script is now in my static folder in Amazon S3 bucket.

When I reload the website, I don't see the panel triggered. Looking at console tells me `GET https://hull2hull-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/debug_toolbar/js/utils.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)` My S3 bucket is private, but Django obviously has access to it. Some other javascripts in static folder are running fine, but not this one. I have even tried to make the whole bucket public for a while, but I was still getting 403. I've added my localhost to CORS.

What's wrong with my setup? Amazon documentation is vast, but not very helpful here.

Comment: did you managed to solve this ?